# Error en JavaFX en eclipse con SceneBuilder no deja crear "New FXML Document"

Tags: eclipse, javafx, fxml

Soy nuevo en todo esto de JavaFX, después de realice la instalación del JavaFX cree un JavaFX Proyect y empecé a crear mi proyecto pero al momento de poner un New FXML Document no me deja crearlo al igual que otras características del JavaFX, me aparece lo siguiente "An error has occurred. See error log for more details.org/eclipse/jface/databinding/swt/WidgetProperties"

[image]

De igual manera si le doy Details>> me aparece el mismo texto sin ninguna descripción extra o sugerencia y no se como solucionarlo

Comment: Que se muestra en el log?, en el diálogo te sugiere revisar

Comment: yo tambien estoy empezando y he estado buscando como resolverlo en internet pero no me aparecio ninguna opcion, lo que yo hice y me sirvio fue crear el documento el Scene builder, primero abri la aplicacion y ya estando adentro le di en save as, al file y luego seleccione la ruta de donde tengo mi programa, basicamente cree el docmuento desde afuera y desde afuera lo meti, tengo el mismo error que tienes, pero haciendo eso me permitio crear el archivo .fxml lo unico que aparece vacio y sin ningun pre pero de esa forma, abrir scenebuilder>save as, la direccion del programa en eclipse, dentro de

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g_RizD9ER-Q este video deberia de ayudare muchisimo

Answer (score 0):

Una solucion practica es que crees FXML manualmente, un archivo y lo guardes con la extension y luego lo abras con scenebuilder. Lo otro que es notable es que usas un componente swt de swing, si vas a trabajar con JavaFX deberias dejar los componentes swing.

NOTA
Deprecated.
This class will be removed in a future release. See https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=546822 for more information. It has been replaced by the class WidgetProperties. That class creates typed property objects, while this class creates raw property objects.

Es un bug de eclipse
[Documentacion](https://rtist.hcldoc.com/help/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjface%2Fdatabinding%2Fswt%2FWidgetProperties.html)